# HTML Table displays random cell values outside of table

Tags: html, vb.net

I am using a string builder to set up an html table row by row so that it can be emailed. I currently gather my information from the database using a data reader and while dataReader.read, I use stringbuilder.Append to add each cell value to the table.

The issue is that after about 200 rows, the html breaks and displays a cell value above the table in the email. I have tried changing the cell padding, but this was not successful. Any suggestions or ideas on why my html table is breaking would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance, and I apologize for the lack of detail in my question.

Comment: There is undoubtedly an error in your `StringBuilder` code - please post how you are building this table. Without some code we won't be able to help very much.

Comment: Can you show some code or an excerpt from the generated HTML?

Comment: unfortunately I cannot show the code at this moment. I will try to make my code as generic as possible, but not sure I have to time to take that step. Again, sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: I am finding that a <td> tag is occasionally changed to <t d="yes">(cell info here)</t>. I found code that was inserting <td>"yes", but after removing this code the error still shows up. I will try to locate any more errors like this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post some example code, so that we can see how you are building the markup? This may help somebody spot the (probably subtle) flaw in your logic

Comment: ...gosh, I *love* guessing-games..

Answer (score 0):

Try running your output through a validator. I suspect you are closing a TR early.

Answer (score 0):

The other thing that could be breaking your markup - especially if the rows are all built with the same code, but the breakage doesn't occur until partway down the table - is if your cell data contains '<' or '>' characters.

If it does, these need to be changed to '&lt;' and '&gt;' respectively.
As you state that you're using vb.net, I suspect that you'll be able to use something like Html.Encode - which is available in c# (Can't say for sure, as I've never used vb.net)

Comment: I have checked this, and there are no '<' or '>' characters in this dataset. This is a good thing to watch out for in the future though, Thanks. I have also tested my code in FireFox and it works as expected. It seems that the HTML is breaking in IE only.

Comment: Have you got HTML validator installed? This is a good tool for checking that your markup is well formed. Just because a page works in one browser, doesn't mean that it is correct - could just be that the browser in question is more tolerant of the fault

Comment: I concur with belugabob. If such errors occur, always run your code through an HTML Validator. You would be surprised how easy it is to miss something.